# Arduino Serial to Processing - can't convert string to int

Tags: arduino, serial-port, integer, processing

I hope this is simple:

Arduino is sending sensor readings as DEC strings. That code is working...it sends strings of Distance Sensor readings. The "number" strings id the sensor and then tell the distance.e.g. 20, 217, 3100, 410

This is how it sends from Arduino:

```java
void printDistance(int id, int dist) {
Serial.print(id);//id's the sensor 
if (dist >=150 || dist <= 0 ) {
 int zero = 0;
  Serial.print(zero, DEC);
} else {
  Serial.print(dist, DEC);
 }
Serial.println("");//line break
}//end print distance
```

In Processing

```java
void draw() {

  if (myPort.available() > 0) { 
     myString = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
     int val = Integer.parseInt(myString);
     //int val = Integer.valueOf(myString);

       if (val >= 0) {

          //center sensor 
        if ((val >= 30 && val <= 39) || (val >= 310 && val <= 399) || (val >= 3100 && val <= 3150)) {
              //playBear(); 
              println(val);
              fill(13, 96, 115); //blue
               rect(150, 150, 100, 100);
             }
            //right sensor   
        else if (((val >= 20) && (val <=29)) || ((val >= 210) && (val <= 299)) || ((val >= 2100) && (val <= 2150))) {
              //playLaugh();
              println(val);
              fill(204, 102, 0); //orange
              rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            }

...more else if's
```

Processing throws a "NumberFormatException for Input String "30"

The question is: How can I get the string from the Arduino Serial actually converted to an integer so I can use it for those badly written conditional statements?

Comment: The correct statement is in your code but it is commented out. Use Integer.parseInt()

Comment: thank you but I've tried both statements and both throw the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Either one of these lines should work:

```java
int val = Integer.parseInt(myString);
int val = Integer.valueOf(myString);
```

If they aren't, then something is wrong with `myString`. Usually the error is caused by the `String` variable containing a non-numeric character, like `"ABC"` or `"XYZ"`.

However, it looks like the value is numeric, since it's printing out `"30"`. So something else is going on.

I wonder if an extra invisible character is being added to the `myString` variable. Try doing stuff like this:

```java
println(myString);
println(myString.length());
```

You could also check out the `Character` class for useful functions, then check every character in `myString` to make sure it holds what you expect.

Comment: I would check for the line terminator. The Arduino println command adds the terminator so that you know it is the end of a line or string. Use trim(MyString) to remove the terminator.

Comment: @mhopeng Yep, that's exactly what I'm guessing is happening. Good advice with the `trim()` function.

Answer (score -1):

try to use myString.toInt  (myString have to be a String object and not a char array )